# How AHIR compilation toolchain (A Hardware Intermediate Representation) is used to compile llvm-IR to VHDL?

Tags: compilation, hardware, fpga

I want to make an application written in C/C++ to work on FPGA. The application works on huge array of binary bits (bitsets). This could work well on data-parallel architecture but GPU's maynot help because of huge data transfers between host and device and little computation on GPU (basically setting and unsetting a bit). So FPGA sounded more promising for this application.

I came across AHIR (Hardware Intermediate Representation) and a compilation toolchain which can compile c algorithms [without recursions] to VHDL. And here is link where [netFPGA](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/atc12/atc12-final16.pdf) worked on this before. They used AHIR as compilation toolchain with llvm-IR. But its not clear how its done. I will be grateful If anyone can explain the sequence of steps to be taken assuming I have an llvm-IR source already as an input to AHIR compiler.

A basic example of C program compiled to VHDL using AHIR would help me too.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: This is the only paper I found -  [AHIR](ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=4092053) which explains the complete design flow of AHIR.

Comment: @zhon I tried rephrasing the question.

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and think about writing a question that will help other (and you) in the future.  Asking someone to write code for you is off topic for SO. Off topic questions only get downvoted and closed.

Comment: @ZHON please reread the question. May be it's not digestible for you. But that's acceptable question